# Auto group synchronization

Tags: active-directory, atlassian-crowd

In our system we use Active Directory to store users and then Crowd server is used to authenticate users to the Atlassian systems.

I need to implement a mechanism to add users to the groups in crowd when a new user in AD syncs with crowd. If user email is ***@xyz.com*** they should be automatically added to ***xyz*** group and If user email is ***@abc.com*** they should be automatically added to ***abc*** group etc.

How can I do this?